# How can I plot from C15 to all the way down indefinitely, so the graph I make changes while I add points?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am making a graph, and as I continue to add points, I want the graph to change, unfortunately, I don't know how many points I will have, so I want the x-axis to range from C15 to an indefinite amount, so that way, as I continue to add points, the graph will simultaneously change

Comment: Are you adding just X, or X and Y points?

Comment: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html

Comment: @TimWilliams - your link is perfect, nothing more to add. Might consider turning it into an answer (copying the essential elements so that the answer remains valid if the link goes stale)

Comment: @Floris - Googling "excel chart dynamic" gives a ton of posts all outlining the same basic concept: if an approach is already well-documented elsewhere I generally don't feel compelled to transcribe it over to SO  ;-P

Comment: @TimWilliams - that's true as long as you understand that you need a word like 'dynamic' in your search. Hitting the right search terms is always key. But now that is captured in the comment we're all good.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert your range into a Table (click on any cell in range, Insert ribbon, Table).

Then any chart that you base on that range will automatically stretch to accomodate new rows.

No formulas are required and Tables have other benefits e.g. Total Row, Named Column references.